# Set tipa font to Times for phonetic characters

Tags: fonts, libertine, tipa, times

I've read in the tipa manual that you can have the tipa font set as Computer Modern (the default) or Times.  I'm using Libertine, so Computer Modern doesn't look great, and Times would look better.  However, I'm not sure how to change the tipa font to Times without changing the whole document to Times.  I figure there must be a way if it's built in.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try `\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{ptm}{m}{n}` after `\usepackage{tipa}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{ptm}{m}{n}` after `\usepackage{tipa}`

Comment: If I in addition to this want slanted characters to work with TIPA, e.g. `\textipa{\textsl{f@"nEtIks}}`, how can I achieve this? I tried `\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{ptm}{m}{sl}` but it made everything in `\textipa{}` slanted.

Comment: @Lundgren8 Ask a new question instead of pinging only me.

Comment: Done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521055/slanted-font-with-tipa-in-xelatex).